# Question about Arrays in Python and Perl?

Tags: python, perl, arrays

How would the following be translated, its an array in perl, I thought that I could translate into python as a list. I am trying to create a program that takes the 2-dimensional shape and basic DNA origami info, and supplies the nodes, the cost, and the range of each DNA strand and also adding a bufferzone and the cleanup zone. When the program receives the information, then it transfers the desired 2-d DNA shape to a three-dimensional DNA origami.

**In Perl:**

```
@xCoords = ();
@yCoords = ();
@zCoords = ();
```

**In Python, what i thought was right?**

```
array(xCoords) = [] 
array(yCoords) = []
array(zCoords) = []
```

Comment: I think you have already received an answer to that question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6900775/need-help-translating-this-array-code-from-perl-to-python . Learning Python and Perl and *rewriting* the code is a better choice than translating it line-by-line relying on someone else's knowledge of the language to do it.

Comment: You should take a look at NumPy, it simplifies working with arrays of numeric data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Base Array:

1. ```
   xCoords = []
   yCoords = []
   zCoords = []
   ```

#### Multidimensional Array:

1. ```
   xCoords = [[]];
   yCoords = [[]];
   zCoords = [[]];
   ```
2. ```
   xCoords = []
   yCoords = []
   zCoords = []
   xCoords.append([])
   yCoords.append([])
   zCoords.append([])
   ```
3. [Credit here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=128110)
   *Example to declare and populate two dimensional array*

   ```
   xCoords = [[]*n for x in xrange(n)]
   yCoords = [[]*n for x in xrange(n)]
   zCoords = [[]*n for x in xrange(n)]
   ```

Comment: 1. is correct, but too complicated. First, `[]*n` results into `[]`, but with a high overhead. But at least it avoids the common mistake to do `[[]]*n`, which creates a list with n times the same list.

`[[] for x in xrange(n)]` is completely sufficient.

Comment: I think I found where I originally discovered that, I'll update my answer with the link.  Note: It declares an `n` by `n` 2D array.

Comment: 3. Is equivalent to `[[] for x in xrange(n)]` - both create a list of n empty lists.

Answer (score 0):

You want this Python:

```
xCoords = []
yCoords = []
zCoords = []
```

You don't need to declare the type with the variables in Python, because Python is dynamically typed.